# Error found when start downloading the binary files from kaa

Tags: java, kaa

In kaa sandbox Iion Demo, while on starting  downloading the java binary sdk for the Notification Demo? But it show an error and cant proceed furthur.!The Error is

> Unexpected error occurred: I/O error on POST request for
>   "http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sdk":I/O error on POST
>   request for "http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sdk":Connect to
>   localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused;
>   nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:

what to do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys any way I found the answer by myself without depending any other sites only by referring Kaa docs.Descriptions and issues of Kaa is very sparingly found on most giant forums.The issue was I cannot download the binary files from KAA from My own pc of RAM 2GB ,wile I found downloading from those PCs more than RAM 2 GB.Actually in documentation it specifys the minimum requirement of PC's as 4 GB .I post this ,becuase someone would elp this.Thanks for all